# Is there any more efficient way to find the basis of the intersection of two subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, dimensional-analysis

> Let $V = \mathbb R^6.$
>
> Let $W_1$ be the subspace of $V$ spanned by
> $$\left ( 1,2,3,4,5,6 \right ) ,\space \left ( 3,4,6,7,9,10 \right ) ,\space \left ( 0,1,0,2,0,3 \right ),\space\left ( 1,-2,3,-4,5,-6 \right ).  $$
>
> Let $W_2$ be the subspace of $V$ spanned by
> $$\left ( 1,1,1,2,2,3 \right ) ,\space \left ( -2,0,-1,0,1,2 \right ) ,\space \left ( 1,0,1,0,2,0 \right ),\space\left ( 0,0,1,0,-2,-2 \right ).$$
>
> Find the dimension of the subspace $W_1\cap W_2$ and find a basis for this subspace.

I know I could take $\forall x=\left ( a,b,c,d,e,f \right ) \in W_1\cap W_2$
$$x=\alpha _1\left ( 1,2,3,4,5,6 \right ) +\space \alpha _2\left ( 3,4,6,7,9,10 \right ) +\space \alpha _3\left ( 0,1,0,2,0,3 \right )+\space\alpha_4 \left ( 1,-2,3,-4,5,-6 \right ) $$

and

$$x=\beta_1 \left ( 1,1,1,2,2,3 \right ) +\space \beta _2\left ( -2,0,-1,0,1,2 \right ) +\space  \beta_3\left ( 1,0,1,0,2,0 \right )+\space\beta _4\left ( 0,0,1,0,-2,-2 \right ).$$

Then

$$\begin{bmatrix}  1&  3&  0&  1& a\\  2&  4&  1&  -2& b\\  3&  6&  0&  3& c\\  4&  7&  2&  -4& d\\  5&  9&  0&  5& e\\  6&  10&  3&  -6&f\end{bmatrix} \text{and} \begin{bmatrix}  1&  -2&  1&  0& a\\  1&  0&  0&  0& b\\  1&  -1&  1&  1& c\\  2&  0&  0&  0& d\\  2&  1&  2&  -2& e\\  3&  2&  0&  -2&f\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then takes so much (tedious) effort to get

$$\begin{bmatrix}  1&  3&  0&  1& a\\  0&  0&  1&  -4& b-\frac{2}{3}c \\  0&  1&  0&  0& a-\frac{1}{3}c \\  0&  0&  0&  0& a-2b-\frac{1}{3}c+d \\  0&  0&  0&  0&  a-2c+e\\  0&  0&  0&  0&2a-3b-\frac{2}{3}c+f\end{bmatrix} \text{and} \begin{bmatrix}  1&  -2&  1&  0& a\\  0&  0&  -1&  -2& b+a-2c \\  0&  1&  0&  1& c-a \\  0&  0&  0&  0& d-2b \\  0&  0&  0&  0&  4e-2a-6c-7f+21b\\  0&  0&  0&  1&\frac{-1}{4}f-\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}c+\frac{3}{4}b    \end{bmatrix}.$$

So $\forall x=\left ( a,b,c,d,e,f \right ) \in W_1\cap W_2$, we have

\begin{align}
a -2b-\frac{1}{3}c+d &=0 \\
a-2c+e &= 0 \\
2a-3b-\frac{2}{3}c +f &=0 \\
4e-2a-6c-7f+21b &=0 \\
d-2b &=0
\end{align}

Finally, we get
$$x=\left ( e,f,3e,2f,5e,3f \right ) $$
so
$$\left \{ \left  (1,0,3,0,5,0 \right ) ,\space \left (0,1,0,2,0,3  \right )   \right \} $$
is a basis for $W_1\cap W_2$.

Is there any efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: It might be (very slightly) more efficient to first transform the spanning sets into bases using the same reduction to echelon form calculations. But although it's indeed tedious it  seems to me quite efficient in that it scarcely engages the brain.

Answer (score 2):

[My prefered *systematic* method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4596055/386889) for calculating an intersection of two subspaces is to have one defined by a basis and the other one defined by equations, and to minimize the number of spanning vectors and equations when choosing which of the two subspaces will play which role. Here,
$$\alpha _1( 1,2,3,4,5,6) +\alpha _2( 3,4,6,7,9,10) +\alpha _3( 0,1,0,2,0,3)+\alpha_4 ( 1,-2,3,-4,5,-6)=\vec0$$
$$\iff\alpha_2=0,\alpha_3=-4\alpha_1,\alpha_4=-\alpha_1,$$
hence forgetting for instance the first of the four spanning vectors gives a basis of $W_1:$
$$u=( 3,4,6,7,9,10),\quad v=( 0,1,0,2,0,3),\quad w=( 1,-2,3,-4,5,-6).$$
Now, solving a system, we find that
$$( a,b,c,d,e,f)\in W_2\iff d=2b\text{ and }-2a+21b-6c+4e-7f=0$$
and we readily derive:
$$\alpha _2u+\alpha _3v+\alpha_4w\in W_2\iff\alpha_2=0.$$
Therefore, a basis of $W_1\cap W_2$ is $(v,w).$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Zaassenhaus algorithm.

*Note: it is very similar to what you did, just organized in a different presentation.*

If $A$ and $B$ are the representive matrices for $W_1$ and $W_2$ where the vectors are disposed in ROWS (not in columns).

Then construct the following matrix $\begin{pmatrix}A & A\\B & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and reduce it to echelon form by only rows operations to $\begin{pmatrix}T_+ & *\\0 & T_\cap\end{pmatrix}$ (where $T_i$ are "upper triangular", I put quotes  because in case of rectangular matrices it is a bit of a language abuse).

Then the rows of $T_+$ form a basis for $W_1+W_2$ and the rows of $T_\cap$ a basis for $W_1\cap W_2$.

Let see what we get in our case, the initial matrix :

$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
3 & 4 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 10 & 3 & 4 & 6 & 7 & 9 & 10 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\
1 & -2 & 3 & -4 & 5 & -6 & 1 & -2 & 3 & -4 & 5 & -6 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

We clear first column by performing $-3r_1,-r_1,-r_1,+2r_1,-r_1$ on the non zero entries ($r_1$ is the first row), then iterate on the second column and so on.

I jump to the result using an online tool (https://planetcalc.com/8328/) with the entry below (if you want to see the detailed steps)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6
3 4 6 7 9 10 3 4 6 7 9 10
0 1 0 2 0 3 0 1 0 2 0 3
1 -2 3 -4 5 -6 1 -2 3 -4 5 -6
1 1 1 2 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
-2 0 -1 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 -2 -2 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The resulting matrix is this one :

$\begin{bmatrix} 
1&0&0&0&0&-\frac27&|&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&\frac57&|&0&0&-6&-2&-12&-4\\
0&0&1&0&0&-\frac67&|&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&\frac87&|&0&0&3&1&6&2\\
0&0&0&0&1&\frac47&|&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0&|&1&0&3&0&5&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&|&0&1&0&2&0&3\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&|&0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$

Where you can identify $(1,0,3,0,5,0)$ and $(0,1,0,2,0,3)$ as a basis of $W_1\cap W_2$.

*Note: the online tool does use fractions, but manually you are not forced to. You can just do $3r_i-5r_j$ for instance when it's convenient. Also the upper part represented by $*$ is not needed you can just ignore these terms entirely in your calculation, resulting in massive speed up. Also doing this you will arrive to multiples like $(0,3,0,6,0,9)$ for instance, but you can always divide by the gcd to tidy up things.*

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at the given vector spanning $W_1$ shows that
$$(1,2,3,4,5,6)=4(0,1,0,2,0,3)+(1,-2,3,-4,5,-6),$$
and so the last vector is in the span of the former three. Applying a few reduction by eye to the remaining three:
$$W_1=\langle(1,0,3,0,5,0),(0,1,0,2,0,3),(1,1,0,1,-1,1)\rangle.\tag{1}.$$
Next note that the last three vectors spanning $W_2$ all have their second and fourth coordinates equal to $0$. Looking at the first vector we see that $W_2$ is contained in the hyperplane $2x_2-x_4=0$. This plane also contains the first two vectors spanning $W_1$ in $(1)$ above, but not the third. It follows that
$$W_1\cap W_2\subseteq\langle(1,0,3,0,5,0),(0,1,0,2,0,3)\rangle.\tag{2}$$
Because so many of the coordinates of the vectors spanning $W_2$ are $0$, it is easy to check that
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1,1,1,2,2,3)&-&(1,0,1,0,2,0)&&&=&(0,1,0,2,0,3),\\
(-2,0,-1,0,1,2)&+3&(1,0,1,0,2,0)&+&(0,0,1,0,-2,-2)&=&(1,0,3,0,5,0),
\end{eqnarray*}
which shows that we have equality in $(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the $6 \times 4$ matrix of the spanning vectors of $W_1$ , and $ B $ be the $6 \times 4$ of the spanning vectors of $W_2$.  The method I used is as follows:

1. Find a basis for the orthogonal complement of $W_1$, by solving $A^T x = 0 $.  Let the vectors of this basis form the $6 \times m_1$ matrix $C$
2. Find a basis for the orthogonal complement of $W_2$ by solving $ B^T x = 0 $.  Let the vectors of this basis form the $6 \times m_2$ matrix $D$.

The intersection of $W_1$ and $W_2$ is orthogonal to both bases $C$ and $D$, hence, to find a basis for the intersection, solve

$ \begin{bmatrix} C^T \\ D^T \end{bmatrix} x = 0 $